# How to color only specific set of words in a string column not the entire cell in pandas data frame?

Tags: python, pandas

I have list of words which needs to be colored if they are appearing in a string in pandas print option in Jupyter

```
import pandas as pd
words=['bullish','bearish','day trading','loss']
df1=pd.DataFrame([[1,'Todays market was bearish and 20 accounts were in loss'],[2,'240 accounts did day trading in bullish market']],columns=['Row', 'Text'])
```

I need to color only Bearish & loss in the first text,bullish  & Day trading in the second text

Todays market was **bearish** and 20 accounts were in **loss**

240 accounts did **day trading** in **bullish** market

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49961211/python-pandas-highlight-matching-text-and-row shows how to use styler to change the background of the cells.  Individual words are not supported unless you go into the individual HTML and reparse it.

Comment: It changes the entire cell color,I want to color only those specific words not the entire string.

Comment: that is the point unless you go and put the dataframe into HTML and then reparse it there is no clean way to do this in the current pandas functionality.

Comment: Thanks Paul, understood.