# How to highlight and count specific keywords in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, regex, pandas

For each row in the `Text` column of my `df`, I want to do the following:

1. Highlight the keywords `gross`,`suck`,`singing` & `ponzi`
2. Count the number of keywords in each row and store them in a `Count` column

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'Text': ['The bread tastes good','Tuna is gross','Teddy is a beach bum','Angela suck at singing!','oneCoin was a ponzi scheme'],
        'ID': [1001,1002,1003,1004,1005]
        }

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['ID', 'Text'])

print(df)
```

The desired output should include the `Count` column and look like this  :

[image]

My attempt (not the best! you can ignore this):

```
# keyword list
key_words = ['gross','suck','singing','ponzi']

# highlight the keywords
df['Text'].applymap(lambda x: "background-color: yellow" if x else "")

# count the keywords present in each row

df['Count'] = df['Text'].str.count(r"\b(?:{})\b".format("|".join(key_words)))
```

All attempts highly appreciated!

Comment: `df['Count'] = df['Text'].str.count(r"\b(?:{})\b".format("|".join(key_words)))`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew- Thanks, that part works fine! what about flagging the `key_words`?

Comment: Where do you need to highlight them? In a Linux terminal? In Jupyter notebook?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, Jupyter notebook or export as csv file?

Comment: It [looks like it is impossible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49961211/python-pandas-highlight-matching-text-and-row).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, Okay, what about we create another column with the `keywords_Present` in  each row (see the revised figure- `keyword_Present`), is this possible?

Comment: I think Ryszard has got it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Series.str.count`:

```py
>>> df['Text'].str.count(fr"\b(?:{'|'.join(key_words)})\b")
0    0
1    1
2    0
3    2
4    1
Name: Text, dtype: int64
```

`\b` is a word boundary, you can get whole word count with it.

You can't highlight separate words in Jupyter notebook. You can extract the words into a separate column:

```py
df['Matches'] = df['Text'].str.findall(fr"\b(?:{'|'.join(key_words)})\b")
```

Comment: thanks, what about the highlighting part? or can we create a new column `Keyword_Present` like in the figure above.

Comment: @RickyTricky Sorry, no highlighting. `df['Keyword_Present'] = df['Text'].str.findall(fr"\b(?:{'|'.join(key_words)})\b").str.join(' ')`  can be used instead.

Answer (score 1):

Use str, find all. That will give you a list. count elements in each list using str.len()

```
df['count']=df['Text'].str.findall('|'.join(key_words)).str.len()
df
```

Comment: Thanks, any luck with the highlighting part of the question?